# grok filter for exec input

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am new to logstash filter creation : can any please suggest the changes on grok filter
was trying to create a grok logstash filter for my ping exec input plugin.. but unable to get parsed message, below are the filter i have applied and error

''''message

Pinging 192.168.10.21 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.21:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),

''''

```
Pinging 192.168.10.21 with 32 bytes of data:
```

Reply from 192.168.10.21: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.21:
Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

I want to segregate both "Request timed out " and reachable with a latency value

Tried with this below filter

filter {
grok {
match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
}
}

getting the error below

```
"@timestamp" => 2020-11-10T11:10:28.479Z
  "@version" => "1",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "_grokparsefailure"
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which logs, you want to filter using grok ?

Comment: @sourav Atta my log is the collection of ping output 

'message 1

Pinging 192.168.10.21 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.10.21: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.21:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 18ms, Average = 18ms

Another log message pattern:

message

Pinging 192.168.10.211 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.211:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),'